# data-driven subscription using oracle stored procedure

Tags: sql, oracle, ssrs-2008

I have been able to create a data-driven subscription for a report (email delivery) where the data comes from an Oracle database (11g) but only if I write the SELECT statement directly within the subscription definition page.

I would rather embed the logic for the SELECT statement within a stored procedure within a package but when I try this and validate the call it always says that '...the query is not valid for the data source'.

I have tried the syntax PACKAGE_NAM.PROC_NAME as well as prefixing this with 'exec' but no luck.

The stored procedure is define as:
PROCEDURE PROC_NAME(pResult OUT refcur) ... where 'refcur' is defined as 'REF CURSOR' which I think is pretty standard and compiles with no errors

Has anybody managed to do what I am trying?  Is it even possible?

Comment: Please show the whole stored procedure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you do it with a function that returns a table? Basically you would do

```
select * from table(my_function(param1,param2))
```

and make the function return the correct datatype (more info here, for example, http://www.akadia.com/services/ora_pipe_functions.html)

Comment: Many thanks. This was a bit of work to define the needed types (the object-type and the collection-type) and then populate the table by iterating over a cursor but at least now we have a single piece of code that all of the data-driven subscriptions can call.

Comment: Glad to help - if you get a moment you might want to mark this as the "Accepted" answer.

Answer (score 0):

> Has anybody managed to do what I am trying? Is it even possible?

Here's an [article](http://blogs.u2u.be/u2u/post/2011/01/30/Using-reporting-services-with-Oracle-package-stored-procedure.aspx) on how to use reporting services against an Oracle Package, so yes its possible and people do it.

More specific help can be given if you post more of the procedure

Comment: Thanks Conrad, but my problem is not with using Oracle for the data-source of reports; we do that extensively here with no problems.  The specific problem/question is how to use an oravle stored procedure as the data-source for a data-driven report subscription, which is created in report manager, not visual studio, BTW.